# sec:authorize does not work - Spring Boot 2, Thymeleaf 3, Thymeleaf Spring Security 5 integration package

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm working with

- Spring Boot 2.2.5
- Thymeleaf 3.0.11
- Thymeleaf Spring Security 5, 3.0.4 Release

I use the following dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Versions are recognized and the respective jars are included in my project. I also have added the extra namespace of Thymeleaf Security Module to my templates:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
```

I have implemented a role based authentication & authorization with Hibernate and MySQL and login / logout, which for my understanding works fine.

The `sec:authentication` tag of Thymeleaf Security Dialect works fine and also displays the correct roles. The `sec:authorize` tag seems to work as well when calling the method `sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"`.
However, I'm struggling when evaluating the role of a user in the templates, both using `sec:authorize="hasRole('...')"` or `th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''...'')')}"`. I seems that the roles cannot be evaluated **although they are correctly displayed using `sec:authentication="principal.authorities"`**.

I have summarized my approaches on a test page, displaying the following result:
[image: showing image]

Any clue where my bug or misunderstanding hides? Many thanks for your support in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research I figured out my issue. After adding the prefix `ROLE_` to the role names (in the datasource), everything works fine.

Comment: You have no idea how much I was suffering due to this. Thanks, you have saved me from pulling my hair.

Comment: Happy that it helped you @Samツ